# nginx if statement inside location returns 404

Tags: nginx, cors

The following block

```conf
location / {
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*\.example\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

… causes a 404 as the above code never reaches the `try_files` directive, so:

1. Is this related to the [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) of nginx?
2. If it is, then is there some other way to test the `http_origin` by not using an if statement?

I have tried this with nginx > 1.4 (1.4.6, 1.7, 1.7.8).

Comment: 1) It's exactly from "if is evil" examples. 2) You could use `map` or use `if` outside of location.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, could you provide an example for how to use `if` outside the location block?

Answer (score 21):

I would use `map`:

```
map $http_origin $cors_header {
    default "";
    "~^https?://[^/]+\.example\.com(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_header;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: What if the allowed origins need to be different for each server?

Comment: Use several `map`s with different variables

Comment: I don't think you want several maps. I believe you can just put additional lines in the single map. As you can see in the answer above, there are two lines: one for the default (nginx config defined server) and another for example.com domains. 

This solution is actually brilliant as you can essentially AllowList a set of domains and nginx will return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value for the domain that is accessing as long as its in the AllowList.